# Local Resource for some controls not generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, localization

So I have a page with a lot of controls on it. I started to translate this page by using the create local resource. For some reason not all controls generate a resource string where I can define the translation. Do I have to specify any special code for them to create a resource string?

A few examples of controls that do not generate resource strings are checkboxes and labels. The strange part is that some do and some dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. When manually adding a meta key to the control you have to define the the resource key in the expression in the control properties. This will link the resource to the control.